# autocomplete with asp.net generated json

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the folowing script which does not seem to work.  The aspx page returns json similar to the json in the script below which has been commented out.  If I stick that json directly into the source as an array, it works perfectly.

But as soon as I try to use the script below, I get no error messages or anything, nothing happens when i type into the autocomplete field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert($("#txtAllowSearchID").val()); 
    }); 

    //var $local_source = [ {id:0,value:"c++"}, {id:1,value:"java"}, {id:2,value:"php"}, {id:3,value:"coldfusion"}, {id:4,value:"javascript"}, {id:5,value:"asp"}, {id:6,value:"ruby"} ]; 

    $("#txtAllowSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test_array.aspx",
                data: "{'prefixText': '" + $('#txtAllowSearch').val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                failure: function(errMsg) {
                    $('#errMessage').text(errMsg);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtAllowSearch").val(ui.item.value); // display the selected text
            $("#txtAllowSearchID").val(ui.item.id); // save selected id to hidden input
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: I think the problem is in the aspx page:

```
objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("select id, value from table1 where value like '%@prefixText%'", objSQLConnection)
objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = "ing"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue might be the source function.  When you make the ajax call, it is done asynchronously.  So, the function kicks off the ajax call and continues, which returns nothing for the source.

I discovered this when I was doing loading screens.  If I put the close for the loading screen after the ajax call, the loading screen would not appear.  I had to move it inside the ajax call success and error events to get it to appear and disappear correctly.

Your source should just be a reference to the url

```
source: "test_array.aspx",
```

From the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote):

> The datasource is a server-side script
>   which returns JSON data, specified via
>   a simple URL for the source-option.

Comment: If I just use the url as described above, how do I post a value to the .aspx page before the .aspx page returns the json data?

Comment: When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The request parameter "term" gets added to that URL. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above. -- So the url it will actually call is `test_array.aspx?term=whateverityped`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have to make the source of the ajax call to a web service, which in your case seems to be a Page Method.  So if you have a function in your code behind page look like this:

```
public static List<string> GetData(string prefixText){ }
```

You would need to decorate that method with `[WebMethod]` from the `System.Web.Services` namespace.

So it would finally look like:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

...

```
[WebMethod()]
public static List<string> GetData(string prefixText){ }
```

HTH

EDIT:  also you would need to update your ajax call to look like this for the source:

```
source: 'test_array.aspx/GetData'
```